# Dynamically allocating an array of size 0

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ new int[0] — will it allocate memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory)

What is supposed to happen when i do this:

```
int * MakeArray( std::size_t Size ) {
    return new int[ Size ];
}

MakeArray( 0 );
```

We had this is out code (using VC++ 2005), and the debug-heap complained about a memory-block of size 0 that was not deallocated. Is it standard to return an array of size 0 here?

P.S.: Please don't tell me to use vector or check for the size before allocation, I know all those. it's not my code. I'm just curious.