# Is there a legal way to define type with zero-size in C++? <eom>

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can sizeof return 0 (zero)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632021/can-sizeof-return-0-zero)

Is there a legal way to define type with zero-size in C++?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html

Comment: If such a thing existed, it would mean you could store an infinite ammount of those types at the same location. Here comes the headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C++ Standard.**

**1.8.5.**
Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more
bytes of storage. Base class sub-objects may have zero size. An object of POD type (3.9) shall occupy
contiguous bytes of storage.

**9.6.2.**
A declaration for a bit-field that omits the identifier declares an unnamed bit-field. Unnamed bit-fields are
not members and cannot be initialized. As a special case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero specifies alignment
of the next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary. Only when declaring an unnamed bit-field may
the constant-expression be a value equal to zero.

Answer (score 9):

No. Even a `struct` with no members has a size.

Comment: but it may be optimized away...

Comment: @flownt with emphasis on *"may"* -- there are certain specific circumstances where such optimisation may be used (e.g. empty sized base class optimisation).

Comment: @flownt: It cannot be optimized away to change the answer to the question: *you cannot define a type with zero size*, even if a subobject in a bigger object may be optimized away.

Answer (score 2):

No, a complete object cannot have a zero size. The reason is the following. Suppose that X is a class/struct with zero size. And you declare an array of X objects:

```
X arr[10];
```

the rule is that *(arr+3) must be the fourth element, but if `sizeof(X)==0` then arr, arr+1 and all others will be equal!!!.

There is one case when a subobject can be of zero size, that is, a base-class subobject. Namely, if you derive class Y from X, where X is an empty class with size, say, 4, then the X subobject in Y may have 0 size.

HTH

Comment: An empty *derived* class can also not add to the size of the class.

Comment: for the derivite classes, this is a good read: http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html

Answer (score 2):

The only legal way to make a type have zero size, is to make it the base of a type that has a size.

```
struct A { };

int cba = sizeof(A); // 1

struct B : A {
  int32_t b;
};

int cbb = sizeof(B); // 4 - implying no storage for A.
```