# What is sizeof(something) == 0?

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I have a template that takes a struct with different values, for example:

```
struct Something
{
    char str[10];
    int value;
    ...
    ...
};
```

And inside the function I use the sizeof operator: jump in memory `sizeof(Something);`

Sometimes I would like to not jump anything at all; I want sizeof to return zero. If I put in an empty struct it will return 1; what can I put in the template to make sizeof return zero?

Comment: Related questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632021/can-sizeof-return-0-zero and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362097/why-is-the-size-of-an-empty-class-in-c-not-zero

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`sizeof` will never be zero.  (Reason: `sizeof (T)` is the distance between elements in an array of type `T[]`, and the elements are required to have unique addresses).

Maybe you can use templates to make a sizeof replacement, that normally uses `sizeof` but is specialized for one particular type to give zero.

e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct jumpoffset_helper
{
    enum { value = sizeof (T) };
};


template <>
struct jumpoffset_helper<Empty>
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

#define jumpoffset(T) (jumpoffset_helper<T>::value)
```

Comment: You can't overload the `sizeof` operator

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - I don't think that is what was suggested, but you can make something that *looks and behaves* similarly, but returns 0 for the cases you care about.

Comment: @awoodland Well, yes, but it can't be called sizeof.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I never said I was going to redefine the `sizeof` keyword, but make something new that could be used instead.

Answer (score 14):

What do you think about it?

```
 #include <iostream>
 struct ZeroMemory {
     int *a[0];
 };
 int main() {
     std::cout << sizeof(ZeroMemory);
 }
```

Yes, output is 0.

But this code is not standard C++.

Comment: yeah, you got me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352663/how-can-this-structure-have-sizeof-0/47352751#47352751

Answer (score 3):

No object in C++ may have a 0 size according to the C++ standard. Only base-class subobjects MAY have 0 size but then you can never call sizeof on those. What you want to achieve is inachievable :)
or, to put it mathematically, the equation

`sizeof x == 0` has no object solution in C++ :)

Comment: The sizeof an empty struct in C would be 0 though, correct? What's the rationale behind enforcing it to be 1 in the C++ standard? And what's the "1", a mandatory padding byte of unknown value?

Comment: because arrays of an empty struct still have to be addressable

Comment: @lundin: It's not actually necessarily 1 byte. It can be 4 (and on my machine it is) or any other nonegative integer for that matter

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed.  I have just experimented with C and C++ (gcc 4.3.2) and the sizeof operator on an empty struct is 0 in C and 1 in C++.