# size of class with empty array in C++

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

AFAIK, the `sizeof` should not return `0`, but the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int a[0];
};

int main() {
   A obj;
   std::cout << sizeof(obj) << std::endl;
}
```

outputs `0`. Why?

Comment: Why do you expect it not being `0`?

Comment: @BartoszKP Because the C++ standard forbids it.

Comment: @Dukeling No, the code is illegal C++ anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can sizeof return 0 (zero)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632021/can-sizeof-return-0-zero)

Comment: @Dukeling In strictly conforming code, yes, the compiler must forbid it. There’s nothing which forbids it as an *extension* to C++, though. I dislike that GCC enables these extensions by default, though.

Comment: `class B : public A
{
      public:
      A a;
};` zero size class optimization works `sizeof(B)` is 0

Comment: @triclosan No, that’s not true. The code is still illegal. The zero-size base class optimisation you talk about does exist, but that doesn’t mean that the *derived class’* size can be 0.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I got it, thanks for clarification blow. My comment was as a joke.

Comment: Try this: `A objs[100];` and then tell us what does `sizeof(objs)` return? If it is still zero, then try printing the addresses of two *consecutive* elements, say `objs[0]` and `objs[1]`. Let us know your findings.

Answer (score 13):

C++ does not allow zero-sized arrays. A conforming compiler rejects the code, e.g.:

```
$ g++-4.8 -pedantic-errors main.cpp
main.cpp:5:14: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'a' [-Wpedantic]
       int a[0];
              ^
```

So the behaviour of `sizeof` here is simply not relevant. GCC allows it (without `-pedantic`) as a [compiler extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: +1: This can be found in 8.3.4§1: *"In a declaration `T D [constant-expression]` [..] the constant-expression (5.19) is present,
it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero"*.

Comment: What is the size of an object of this class in GCC? I suppose its the size of the pointer. what is it?

Comment: @hasan There is no point in discussing what a faulty implementation should return in such case. Size of array should not be 0

Comment: Didn't you say that gcc allow it.

Comment: so in gcc its not faulty?!

Comment: What if array have size larger than zero. does pointer have size? or just the array?