# Why does a lambda have a size of 1 byte?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, sizeof

I am working with the memory of some lambdas in C++, but I am a bit puzzled by their size.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  auto f = [](){ return 17; };
  std::cout << f() << std::endl;
  std::cout << &f << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(f) << std::endl;
}
```

The ouptut is:

```
17
0x7d90ba8f626f
1
```

This suggests that the size of my lambda is 1.

- How is this possible?
- Shouldn't the lambda be, at minimum, a pointer to its implementation?

Comment: its implemented as a function object (a `struct` with an `operator()`)

Comment: And an empty struct can not be size 0 hence the 1 result. Try capturing something and see what happens to the size.

Comment: Why should a lambda be a pointer??? It's an object that has a call operator.

Comment: Lambdas in C++ exist at compile-time, and invocations are linked (or even inlined) at compile or link time. There's therefore no need for a *runtime* pointer in the object itself. @KerrekSB It's not an unnatural guess to expect that a lambda would contain a function pointer, since most languages that implement lambdas are more dynamic than C++.

Comment: @KyleStrand: That's a fairly vague statement. A lambda is an expression, and the expression does indeed exist at compile time, but what matters is the *value* you obtain from evaluating that expression, which is the closure object, and that exists at runtime. Expression evaluation happens (as-if) at runtime (except for constant expressions).

Comment: @KerrekSB "what matters" -- in what sense? The *reason* a closure object can be empty (rather than containing a function pointer) is *because* the function to be called is known at compile/link time. This is what the OP seems to have misunderstood. I don't see how your comments clarify things.

Comment: If you ever need a type's true size rather than sizeof's lie, you can use `return std::is_empty_v<T> ? 0 : sizeof(T);`. I used this in certain templated classes to determine whether a lambda has any state or not. `#define true_sizeof(T) TrueSizeof<std::remove_reference_t<T> >()`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The lambda in question actually has *no state*.

Examine:

```
struct lambda {
  auto operator()() const { return 17; }
};
```

And if we had `lambda f;`, it is an empty class.  Not only is the above `lambda` functionally similar to your lambda, it is (basically) how your lambda is implemented!  (It also needs an implicit cast to function pointer operator, and the name `lambda` is going to be replaced with some compiler-generated pseudo-guid)

In C++, objects are not pointers.  They are actual things.  They only use up the space required to store the data in them.  A pointer to an object can be larger than an object.

While you might think of that lambda as a pointer to a function, it isn't.  You cannot reassign the `auto f = [](){ return 17; };` to a different function or lambda!

```
 auto f = [](){ return 17; };
 f = [](){ return -42; };
```

the above is *illegal*.  There is no room in `f` to store *which* function is going to be called -- that information is stored in the *type* of `f`, not in the value of `f`!

If you did this:

```
int(*f)() = [](){ return 17; };
```

or this:

```
std::function<int()> f = [](){ return 17; };
```

you are no longer storing the lambda directly.  In both of these cases, `f = [](){ return -42; }` is legal -- so in these cases, we are storing *which* function we are invoking in the value of `f`.  And `sizeof(f)` is no longer `1`, but rather `sizeof(int(*)())` or larger (basically, be pointer sized or larger, as you expect.  `std::function` has a min size implied by the standard (they have to be able to store "inside themselves" callables up to a certain size) which is at least as large as a function pointer in practice).

In the `int(*f)()` case, you are storing a function pointer to a function that behaves as-if you called that lambda.  This only works for stateless lambdas (ones with an empty `[]` capture list).

In the `std::function<int()> f` case, you are creating a type-erasure class `std::function<int()>` instance that (in this case) uses placement new to store a copy of the size-1 lambda in an internal buffer (and, if a larger lambda was passed in (with more state), would use heap allocation).

As a guess, something like these is probably what you think is going on.  That a lambda is an object whose type is described by its signature.  In C++, it was decided to make lambdas *zero cost* abstractions over the manual function object implementation.  This lets you pass a lambda into a `std` algorithm (or similar) and have its contents be fully visible to the compiler when it instantiates the algorithm template.  If a lambda had a type like `std::function<void(int)>`, its contents would not be fully visible, and a hand-crafted function object might be faster.

The goal of C++ standardization is high level programming with zero overhead over hand-crafted C code.

Now that you understand that your `f` is in fact stateless, there should be another question in your head: the lambda has no state.  Why does it not size have `0`?

---

There is the short answer.

All objects in C++ must have a minimium size of 1 under the standard, and two objects of the same type cannot have the same address.  These are connected, because an array of type `T` will have the elements placed `sizeof(T)` apart.

Now, as it has no state, sometimes it can take up no space.  This cannot happen when it is "alone", but in some contexts it can happen.  `std::tuple` and similar library code exploits this fact.  Here is how it works:

As a lambda is equivalent to a class with `operator()` overloaded, stateless lambdas (with a `[]` capture list) are all empty classes.  They have `sizeof` of `1`.  In fact, if you inherit from them (which is allowed!), they will take up no space *so long as it doesn't cause a same-type address collision*.  (This is known as the empty base optimization).

```
template<class T>
struct toy:T {
  toy(toy const&)=default;
  toy(toy &&)=default;
  toy(T const&t):T(t) {}
  toy(T &&t):T(std::move(t)) {}
  int state = 0;
};

template<class Lambda>
toy<Lambda> make_toy( Lambda const& l ) { return {l}; }
```

the `sizeof(make_toy( []{std::cout << "hello world!\n"; } ))` is `sizeof(int)` (well, the above is illegal because you cannot create a lambda in a non-evaluated context: you have to create a named `auto toy = make_toy(blah);` then do `sizeof(blah)`, but that is just noise).  `sizeof([]{std::cout << "hello world!\n"; })` is still `1` (similar qualifications).

If we create another toy type:

```
template<class T>
struct toy2:T {
  toy2(toy2 const&)=default;
  toy2(T const&t):T(t), t2(t) {}
  T t2;
};
template<class Lambda>
toy2<Lambda> make_toy2( Lambda const& l ) { return {l}; }
```

this has *two copies* of the lambda.  As they cannot share the same address, `sizeof(toy2(some_lambda))` is `2`!

Comment: Nit:  A function pointer can be smaller than a void*.  Two historical examples:  Firstly word addressed machines where sizeof(void*)==sizeof(char*) > sizeof(struct*) == sizeof(int*).  (void* and char* needs some extra bits to hold the offset within a word).Secondly the 8086 memory model where void*/int* was segment+offset and could cover all of memory, but functions fitted within a single 64K segment (so a function pointer was only 16 bits).

Comment: @martin true.  Extra `()` added.

Answer (score 54):

A lambda is not a function pointer.

A lambda is an instance of a class. Your code is approximately equivalent to:

```
class f_lambda {
public:

  auto operator() { return 17; }
};

f_lambda f;
std::cout << f() << std::endl;
std::cout << &f << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(f) << std::endl;
```

The internal class that represents a lambda has no class members, hence its `sizeof()` is 1 (it cannot be 0, for reasons adequately stated [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632021/can-sizeof-return-0-zero)).

If your lambda were to capture some variables, they'll be equivalent to class members, and your `sizeof()` will indicate accordingly.

Answer (score 27):

Your compiler more or less translates the lambda to the following struct type:

```
struct _SomeInternalName {
    int operator()() { return 17; }
};

int main()
{
     _SomeInternalName f;
     std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Since that struct has no non-static members, it has the same size as an empty struct, which is `1`.

That changes as soon as you add a non-empty capture list to your lambda:

```
int i = 42;
auto f = [i]() { return i; };
```

Which will translate to

```
struct _SomeInternalName {
    int i;
    _SomeInternalName(int outer_i) : i(outer_i) {}
    int operator()() { return i; }
};


int main()
{
     int i = 42;
     _SomeInternalName f(i);
     std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Since the generated struct now needs to store a non-static `int` member for the capture, its size will grow to `sizeof(int)`. The size will keep growing as you capture more stuff.

(Please take the struct analogy with a grain of salt. While it's a nice way to reason about how lambdas work internally, this is not a literal translation of what the compiler will do)

Answer (score 13):

> Shouldn't the lambda be, at mimumum, a pointer to its implementation?

Not necessarily. According to the standard, the size of the unique, unnamed class is *implementation-defined*. Excerpt from **[expr.prim.lambda]**, C++14 (emphasis mine):

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> **An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below** provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program **other than by changing**:
>
> **— the size and/or alignment of the closure type**,
>
> — whether the closure type is trivially copyable (Clause 9),
>
> — whether the closure type is a standard-layout class (Clause 9), or
>
> — whether the closure type is a POD class (Clause 9)

In your case -- for the compiler you use -- you get a size of 1, which doesn't mean it's fixed. It can vary between different compiler implementations.

Comment: Are you sure this bit applies? A lambda without a capture-group isn't really a "closure." (Does the standard refer to empty-capture-group lambdas as "closures" anyway?)

Comment: Yes, it does. This is what the standard says "_The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary. This temporary is called the closure object._", capturing or not, it's a closure object, just that one will be void of upvalues.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but possibly the downvoter doesn't think this answer is valuable because it doesn't explain *why* it's possible (from a theoretical perspective, not a standards perspective) to implement lambdas without including a run-time pointer to the call-operator function. (See my discussion with KerrekSB under the question.)

Answer (score 8):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda:

> The lambda expression constructs an unnamed prvalue temporary object of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type, **known as closure type**, which is declared (for the purposes of ADL) in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda expression.
>
> **If the lambda-expression captures anything by copy** (either implicitly with capture clause [=] or explicitly with a capture that does not include the character &, e.g. [a, b, c]), **the closure type includes unnamed non-static data members**, declared in unspecified order, that hold copies of all entities that were so captured.
>
> For the entities that are **captured by reference** (with the default capture [&] or when using the character &, e.g. [&a, &b, &c]), it is **unspecified if additional data members are declared** in the closure type

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

> When applied to an empty class type, always returns 1.