# Possible storage waste of storing lambda into std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

The size of a lambda expression object with an empty capture-list is 1

But if you store it into `std:function`, its size becomes 48 (on my platform)

Imagine when you have a container that stores thousands of functions

The memory usage will be 48-times bigger if you store them into `std::function`

Even a lambda object capturing a small object (like an 8-sized pointer) is much smaller than a `std::function`

Do you have any better idea to save that unnecessary space-usage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a lambda have a size of 1 byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481767/why-does-a-lambda-have-a-size-of-1-byte)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès No, I know the lambda things, the problem is about `std::function`

Comment: If your lambdas are all non-capturing then just use function pointers otherwise, unless they are all the same lambda, you need to pay the cost of `std::function` to provide the type erasure. If you need to worry about 48K of memory then your container with thousands of functions is probably not appropriate anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the price you pay for not needing to know the type of the function. All `std::function<void()>`s are interchangeable no matter which lambda they came from. If you want to store lots of the same type of function (with different captures) in a vector, you can make it a functor instead of a lambda (so that it has a name) and make a vector *of that type*.

Example: With lambda:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> funcs;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    funcs.push_back([i]() {std::cout << i << std::endl;});
for(auto& func : funcs)
    func();
```

With functor:

```
struct number_printing_function {
    int i;
    number_printing_function(int i) : i(i) {}
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<number_printing_function> funcs;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    funcs.push_back(number_printing_function(i));
    // or funcs.emplace_back(i);

for(auto& func : funcs)
    func();
```

---

IMO this is a bit useless, because we might as well store a vector of ints and stop pretending they are functions. When you have many functors of the same type you already know what they do, so just do it. Really, the code above is just the code below, but with extra steps:

```
std::vector<int> ints;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    ints.push_back(i);
for(auto& i : ints)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: you can return a lambda from a function, e.g. `auto make_func(int i) { return [i](){ std::cout << i << std::endl; }; }`, `std::vector<decltype(make_func(0))> funcs; std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(funcs), 10000, make_func);`

Comment: @Caleth While this is true, it's much more convenient to give the functor a name so you can do things like pass it around. I mean, great, you created a vector of lambdas, but how are you going to store it in a member variable or pass it as a parameter? A name is a lot easier to type and remember than a decltype expression.