# Check for Complete type

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I came across this code in `boost/checked_delete.hpp`

Can somebody explain what are line#1 and line#2 doing?

```
template<class T> inline void checked_array_delete(T * x)
{
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];     #1 
    (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);                       #2
    delete [] x;
}
```

From this [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/core/doc/html/core/checked_delete.html), I got this info regarding their purpose,

```
T must be a complete type. The expression delete [] p must be well-formed.
```

but, what is a *complete type* in C++?

Comment: `#2` is not silent warning for unused local type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer that, one needs to answer what is an *incomplete* type. The standard actually has a definition ([[basic.types]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#5)):

> A class that has been declared but not defined, an enumeration type in
>   certain contexts ([dcl.enum]), or an array of unknown bound or of
>   incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type.
>   Incompletely-defined object types and cv void are incomplete types
>   ([basic.fundamental]). Objects shall not be defined to have an
>   incomplete type.

The "certain contexts" refers to situations when there isn't a complete definition of the type yet. For instance, a forward declaration of an enum `enum foo : int;` declares an incomplete type.

Now, since `sizeof` may not be applied to incomplete types ([[expr.sizeof]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sizeof#1)):

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function or incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such types,
>   or to a glvalue that designates a bit-field.

That `typedef` is ill-formed for any type the standard lists in the first quoted paragraph. And you'll get an error message that includes the text `type_must_be_complete`.

And just in case there is some [pathological compiler extension that allows a type to have 0 size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632021/can-sizeof-return-0-zero), the author is being cautious and making sure the array definition is still ill-formed, by giving it a negative size. So you won't be calling `delete[]` in those pathological case either.

Comment: Cool. But there is no if-else clause or return statement then how are we avoiding the `delete []` at the end of function?

Comment: @SauravSahu - Since an incomplete type will make the above ill formed the code won't compile. It won't silently leak memory at run time.