# Allocating memory by size zero in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
int a = 10;
int *p = new int[0];

p = &a;
cout << *p << endl;
```

In c++, what happens if allocate memory size by zero?

after allocation I get valid memory pointer, and prints valid number.

But I think new operator should return something like FAILD or NULL.

Can anybody explain detail?

Comment: The second half of your example has nothing to do with the allocation. You just "forgot" the allocation, leaked memory, and used a's allocated memory.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In c++, what happens if allocate memory size by zero?

A zero sized array is valid.
You just can't de-reference any members.

This is why the Greeks spent such a long time debating it thinking about zero as a number. But we can thank India at its great minds for eventually bringing zero as a number 0. It took them forever and aren't we glad they did, a lot of modern maths would not be possible without such a unique value.

> after allocation I get valid memory pointer,

That is correct.
If it failed it would throw an exception.

> and prints valid number.

Your assignment: `p = &a;` is probably not what you want. As this just leaks memory and set p to point at the variable a. What you were probably trying to do is:

```
(*p) = a;
// or
p[0] = a;
```

This is undefined behavior.
As you are assigning to values after the end of the array.

> But I think new operator should return something like FAILD or NULL.

No.

> Can anybody explain detail?

Yes.

Answer (score 3):

> after allocation I get valid memory pointer, and prints valid number.

Your provided code doesn't actually test this.

When you do `p = &a`, you're *reassigning* `p` *to point somewhere completely different*. Whatever it held before is irrelevant to the continued execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the pointer "p" at the chunk of "a" so p doesn't point to the zero size chunk anymore when you print it.

Answer (score 1):

From ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E), 5.3.4.6

> Every constant-expression in a direct-new-declarator shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) and evaluate to a strictly positive value. The expression in a direct-new-declarator shall have integral or enu- meration type (3.9.1) with a non-negative value. [Example: if n is a variable of type int, then new float[n][5] is well-formed (because n is the expression of a direct-new-declarator), but new float[5][n] is ill-formed (because n is not a constant-expression). If n is negative, the effect of new float[n][5] is undefined.]

They are intelligent. Can zero be considered as `non-negative value` ? Might be yes, since it is compiling with no problems, I guess.

Comment: Those are nice, but say nothing about the size 0 case (which I think is expected to succeed, and return a valid **unique** address).

Comment: @Ben Voigt - This would be right excerpt, I hope. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yes, zero is most definitely non-negative.  Note that earlier in that rule they said "strictly positive" when they didn't want to allow zero.

Answer (score 1):

From ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E), 5.3.4.7

> When the value of the expression in
>   a direct-new-declarator is zero, the
>   allocation function is called to
>   allocate an array with no elements.

So you get a valid pointer, but you can't dereference it, and must still delete[] it.