# Deleting and re-allocating global pointer - segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, global-variables

I have in test.h file:
`double *condmatrix` - global variable
Then in the main program I do:

```
cycle_start {
    proc1() {
    condmatrix = new double[maxdim];
    ....simple work with the array itself
    }
    proc2() {
    delete [] condmatrix;
    }
}//cycle finish
```

This gives me a segfault. I tried deleted with [] syntax, without and other ways, it still gives a segfault. Maxdim varies from cycle to cycle.

Comment: Looks all right. Can you give us a minimal complete example?

Comment: perhaps you are trying to delete it twice

Comment: Which is the value of maxdim? see [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory)

Comment: no, maxdim isn't equal to zero.
within the cycle all I do is fill it with random numbers and then normalize every element (so that sum equals 1)

Comment: you are probably corrupting memory somewhere. check if you are crossing boundries.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that I allocated a pointer twice, that is:

```
condmatrix = new double [maxdim];
condmatrix = new double [maxdim];
delete [] condmatrix;
```

I know this shouldn't cause the problem, but evidently it did, because after rewriting the code to allocate once, it works perfect. Maybe there was some memory corruption, which I occasionally fixed.