# C++ memory leak with 2d array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, delete-operator

The three functions below contain memory leaks at the lines marked with "// memory leak vvv" according to Dr. Memory. I'm relatively new to C++ and pointers and am not sure why these lines are causing leaks. "values_" is a T** and is a member variable for the UndoArray class.

```
template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::set(size_type i, const T& v) {
    counts_[i]++;
    if(!initialized(i)) {
        // memory leak vvv
        values_[i] = new T[1];
        values_[i][0] = v;
    } else {
        // memory leak vvv
        T* temp = new T[counts_[i]];
        for(int j = 0; j < counts_[i] - 1; j++) {
            temp[j] = values_[i][j];
        }
        temp[counts_[i] - 1] = v;
        delete [] values_[i];
        values_[i] = temp;
    }
}

template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::undo(size_type i) {
    counts_[i]--;
    if(counts_[i] == 0) {
        values_[i] = NULL;
    } else {
        T* temp = values_[i];
        // memory leak vvv
        values_[i] = new T[counts_[i]];
        for(int j = 0; j < counts_[i]; j++) {
            values_[i][j] = temp[j];
        }
        delete [] temp;
    }
}

template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::copy(const UndoArray<T>& ua) {
    size_ = ua.size_;
    counts_ = new unsigned[size_];
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        counts_[i] = ua.counts_[i];
    }
    values_ = new T*[size_];
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        if(counts_[i] == 0) {
            values_[i] = NULL;
        } else {
            // memory leak vvv
            values_[i] = new T[counts_[i]];
            for(int j = 0; j < counts_[i]; j++) {
                values_[i][j] = ua.values_[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor for UndoArray uses...

```
template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::create() {
    size_ = 0;
    counts_ = new unsigned[size_];
    values_ = new T*[size_];
}
```

... if the default constructor is called (no arguments) or ...

```
template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::create(size_type n) {
    size_ = n;
    counts_ = new unsigned[size_];
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        counts_[i] = 0;
    values_ = new T*[size_];
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        values_[i] = NULL;
}
```

... if an initial array size is specified.

The destructor looks like...

```
template <class T> UndoArray<T>::~UndoArray() {
    delete [] counts_;
    if(values_ != NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
            delete [] values_[i];
        }
    }
    delete [] values_;
}
```

Comment: What does the destructor for `UndoArray` look like?

Comment: @ZacHowland I edited my original question and added the constructors.

Comment: Not the constructors ... the Destructors.  That is, the method that gets called when your class is destroyed and is suppose to clean up it's resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that are not ok in the code:

I.e.

```
template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::copy(const UndoArray<T>& ua) {
size_ = ua.size_;
counts_ = new unsigned[size_];
for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
    counts_[i] = ua.counts_[i];
}
//What if values_ is not null here? You do not delete the old data
values_ = new T*[size_];
```

And there are some more situations in the code you posted where you do something similar.

Edit1: To give you another example

```
template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::undo(size_type i) {
counts_[i]--;
if(counts_[i] == 0) {
    //what if values_[i] != nullptr here? You will leak the old value...
    values_[i] = NULL;
```

Of course you should make sure that you delete each pointer in the destructor.

like:

```
~UndoArray()
{
  if (nullptr != values_)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
      {
         delete [] values[i];
      }

      delete [] values;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was missing deleting each pointer in values_ e.g. the for loop that you mentioned in your destructor. After I added that the only leak I have is in the set function where I try `values_[i] = new T[1];`.

Comment: Please note that you should revise your create method you posted with one of your edits. You are basically allocating a zero sized array. I will not go into the details but you should probably read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory

Comment: If `values_i[i]` has an allocated memory block attached to it, it will leak there.  You need to test it, delete what is there, and then you can assign it a new memory block.

Comment: Please see the above two other examples where it may be that you should delete the allocated memory. I saw at least one more such example of missing deletes.

Comment: I think you are going to constantly get into trouble if you will have to do this type of memory management all over the UndoArray class implementation. Probably it would be better to wrap the values_ stuff in a separate class with a simple and clear interface and do the memory management in that single place... Probably you could replace values_ with a std::vector<T>* values_

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T> void UndoArray<T>::set(size_type i, const T& v) {
    counts_[i]++;
    if(!initialized(i)) {
        // memory leak vvv`
```

this is a leak because values_[i] is never deleted.

```
    values_[i] = new T[1];
    values_[i][0] = v;
} else {
    // memory leak vvv
```

same problem here.  there is no delete temp; statement.

```
    T* temp = new T[counts_[i]];
    for(int j = 0; j < counts_[i] - 1; j++) {
        temp[j] = values_[i][j];
    }
    temp[counts_[i] - 1] = v;
    delete [] values_[i];
    values_[i] = temp;
}
```

You must call delete on the newed memory.  Unless the destructor of the class cleans up values_.

Comment: He copies `values_i[i]` to `temp` and deletes `temp`.

Comment: Not in the ::set method.  In the ::undo method, yes.

Comment: He has a `delete [] values_i[i]` in the set method as well.

Comment: The destructor of the class now cleans up values_ well and my only leak now is in the set function when I try `values[i] = new T[1];`.

Comment: @rileyberton:  For the 2nd allocation (in the else-condition), I meant.  I apparently improperly assumed `initialized(i)` tested to see if the `values_i[i]` block had been allocated.