# What does "new int[];" do?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, new-operator

What does this line of code do?

```
new int[];
```

According to my compiler's disassembly (VC++ 2012), it does the same as:

```
new int[0];
```

But is it specified by the C++ standard? And is it a legal instruction?

Comment: Lightning doesn't strike twice and all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory

Comment: Sounds like either a bug or an extension.

Comment: AFAIK that's a Visual C++ bug. There is a related bug where it (in some contexts) accepts the syntax `delete[n] p`. I've reported the latter.

Comment: Seriously, how can a question about `new int[]` be a duplicate of one about `new int[0]`, when the former is never even mentioned in the latter?

Comment: **Oh no**, in addition to sillyvoting, now an incorrect answer selected as the "solution". @NPS: please do reconsider your choice. People landing here by googling will be misinformed with the current choice.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf From what I understood "new int[];" isn't legal. If you're conviced it is please provide your own answer and quote the standard - I'll be happy to reconsider my choice.

Comment: @NPS Excuse Alf, he's often unclear in his saint anger :) What he means is that the answer is incorrect by saying *"[] requires constant expression"*, which whould mean you couldn't do `new int[i]`, where `i` is a runtime value. That would beat the purpose of dynamic initialization.

Comment: I was wondering : what is the point of such code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `new int[]` is not valid with C++11 (I have not checked C++14).

With a single `[]` the syntax requires an (implicitly convertible to) integral type *expression* between the brackets, denoting the desired array size.

Note that this size needs not be a constant: at the bottom level of abstraction this is how you allocate a dynamic array in C++.

---

C++11 (via the N3290 final draft) §5.3.4/6:

> **”** Every *constant-expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) and
>   evaluate to a strictly positive value. The *expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be of integral type,
>   unscoped enumeration type, or a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or
>   unscoped enumeration type exists (12.3)

*expression* is used for the first `[]` brackets. In subsequent `[]` brackets one must use a *constant-expression* (value known at compile time) because addressing of the outermost array dimension requires known size array items.

---

Of course, instead of using `new` directly you will generally be better off using a `std::vector` (or maybe `std::string`).

Comment: Or maybe `std::dynarray` or `std::valarray`, which are both awesome contiguous containers.

Comment: @Yakk: Well there is no `std::dynarray`. There is `std::valarray` but it's very little used. Reportedly the design was incomplete but yet it somehow found its way int C++98.

Answer (score 7):

```
new int[];
```

is not legal.

As per the draft standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) § 5.3.4, `[]` should have an *expression* for the first dimension, and a *constant-expression* for each subsequent dimension (if any), as dictated by the grammar:

```
noptr-new-declarator:
     [ expression ] attribute-specifier-seqopt
     noptr-new-declarator [ constant-expression ] attribute-specifier-seqopt
```

Here, every *constant-expression* shall be a converted constant expression, as specified in clause 6:

> Every *constant-expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be a
>   converted constant expression (5.19) of type std::size_t and shall
>   evaluate to a strictly positive value. The *expression* in a
>   *noptr-new-declarator* is implicitly converted to std::size_t.

Comment: And standard quote is where?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a constant expression. Perhaps more relevant is the grammar specification for *noptr-new-declarator*, requiring an expression inside the `[]`.

Comment: The grammar says *constant-expression*, which doesn't mean "constant expression". Perhaps it'd be better if you italicized it to make it clear.

Comment: @remyabel *const-expression* means what it means. But it's only required when you're dynamically allocating arrays, e.g. `new int[i][5];` Means you can't have a non-constant expressions in place of `5`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm no C/C++ expert, nor have any intention to become in near future, please add your own answer, or edit this. Otherwise I'll be more then happy to delete and learn more, thanks !

Comment: @P0W "[] should have constant-expression" is incorrect if you think about it for a second.

Comment: @jrok yeah I get that, but I'm "out of words" to re-word it :(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It would be only fair to remove your downvote now :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you ! you've my +1, jrok amd remyabel thanks a bunch for edits.

Comment: @cheers Which draft are you using? It appears to me that 5.3.4/6 for [n3242](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) and [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) are exactly the same.

Comment: @P0W: here's the standardeese from N3337: "Every constant-expression in a noptr-new-declarator shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) and
evaluate to a strictly positive value. The expression in a noptr-new-declarator shall be of integral type,
unscoped enumeration type, or a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or
unscoped enumeration type exists (12.3" AFAICS it is identical to C++11 (N3290). It does not match the quoted text in the answer.