# Unable to use delete "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Here is my function:

```
void Tetris::place_square(int* coords,char type){
    if (coords[1]>heights[coords[0]]){
        char* old=data[coords[0]];
        data[coords[0]]=new char[coords[1]];
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<heights[coords[0]]; ++i){
            data[coords[0]][i]=old[i];
        }
        for (unsigned int i=heights[coords[0]]; i<coords[1]; ++i){
            data[coords[0]][i]=" "[0];
        }
        data[coords[0]][coords[1]-1]=type;
        heights[coords[0]]=coords[1];
        delete old;
    } else {
        data[coords[0]][coords[1]-1]=type;
    }
}
```

It compiles fine but when I try to run it i get `malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff503e0020: pointer being freed was not allocated`

I believe the problem is `delete old;` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How do you fill `data` and `coords` before calling `place_square`?

Comment: `data[coords[0]];` was initialized with `data[i]=new char[0];`

coords is just an array of size two with two ints `coords[0]` is always a valid index for data

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this section:

```
char* old=data[coords[0]];
data[coords[0]]=new char[coords[1]];
```

I'm not sure what is in your `data` array, but it looks like you are assigning a pointer which has not yet been initialized.

If you are initializing with

```
data[i]=new char[0];
```

Then you should also be deleting with `delete[]`.

Comment: No, `data[coords[0]];` was initialized with `data[i]=new char[0];`

Comment: Is there a reason you are initializing your array that way? That effectively just doubles the number of pointers you have to free later.  Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory) concerning allocations of size 0.

Answer (score 1):

The address indicates that `data[coords[0]]` was previously pointing to an automatic variable. You can only use `delete` on things that were allocated by `new`.

Also, you should use `delete[]` when things were allocated by `new[]` as they are in this example.

To fix this you will need to review the initialization of `data` and any code that might update `data[x]` .  It is also possible that `coords[0]` is out of bounds for `data`.

Comment: `data[coords[0]];` was initialized with `data[i]=new char[0];`

Comment: @DanG. the error message indicates that it wasn't . To get better help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).