# create an array without entering the size in the new[] statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

By mistake i forgot to enter the size of the array and wrote something like

```
int* ptr = new int[];
```

I was surprised when the code compiled. So, now since it compiled; could anyone let me know what is the meaning of this? it is creating an array of size?

Comment: What compiler? I don't think it is standard.

Comment: @RobertPrévost i am using visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at the disassembly, this is just a non-standard way of saying `int* ptr = new int[0];` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory) for what that means).