# Use `delete []` when `new [0]`

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

I dynamically allocated an array (`unsigned int n` might have been passed as a parameter in a function):

```
int * ar = new int [n];
```

When I'm done using it:

```
delete [] ar;
```

But, what happens when `n = 0`?
Is allocate `0` `int`s the same as not allocating at all?
In which case, do **bad things happen** when I call `delete`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory And you do allocate something (data for managing your allocation at least) - it's not the same as doing nothing.

Comment: @deviantfan -- My bad! I didn't find any duplicates because I was phrasing as "can you `delete` `0`", whereas your link phrased it as "can you `new` `0`" (in the end, it's kinda the same thing). Should I delete this Q?

Comment: Use std::vector!

Comment: @FineMan I don't think you can ... anyways, duplicates help at least for others finding this, then following the link. And you got a answer here too. No need to worry.

Comment: @deviantfan -- Good point. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok to `new` a zero-sized array, and to `delete` it. This is more of a convenience than anything, as it means you don't have to write separate conditions for the `0` case.

Comment: As long as you don't try to actually *use it* for anything ;-)

Comment: _Phew!_ As I'm very lazy, I went all the way to ask a Q on SO to make sure I don't need to write separate conditions for `0`. `:D`