# allocate new Zero-sized array can have effective value?

Tags: c++

// new T[0] allocate a zero sized array can have values?

```
auto pv=new int[0];
cout<<pv<<endl; //0x... ?
*pv=123;
cout<<*pv<<endl; //123 ?
delete[] pv;
```

Why? 
if so, what's difference between new T[0] and new T[1]

Why can I set the value of 0 sized array ...?

Comment: You are using pointer arithmetic to scribble over adjacent memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ new int\[0\] -- will it allocate memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Not really; whether it allocates memory or not, `pv[0]` is logically out of bounds.

Comment: Does it actually allocate the memory?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think we can't discuss about UB. As after `auto pv=new int[0];` everything could happen, I wouldn't argue that something could be logically out of bounds

Comment: @Larry It allocates some memory. It does not allocate memory that is available for use by you as an `int` element of the array.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX `new int[0]` does not have undefined behaviour. So the out-of-bounds expression (via the dereference) is the _only_ relevant thing.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Allocating the memory is not UB by itself.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings oh yes you are right. But the dereferencing is UB

Comment: @Larry To maintain the compiler's heap data structure, it may allocate memory, but that is only for the structure's internals.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Yes, because it is an operation that attempts to navigate logically out of bounds of the array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's also because every [concurrently extant] object in C++ must have a unique address.

Comment: So, the system does allocate some ghost memory, but I can't use it, and I must deallocate this ghost memory? delete [] pv; ? Is it right

Comment: @Larry -- Imagine if you created a home-made `vector` class, where on construction, you took in a `size_t size` parameter to denote the number of entries.  The user passes in a `0` for `size`.   It is perfectly valid in your class to do something like `new T[size]`, where `size==0`.

Comment: It depends on memory allocator in you libc/libstd C++. More likely yes then no, since memory allocators usually allocating minimally `sizeof(size_t)` bytes. I.e. for 64bit instruction set, for range `0..8` memory allocator will reserve 8 bytes. In any case no any guaranty according to standard this is `undefined behavior`.

Answer (score 7):

It is legal to create a `new int[0]` (though at first glance it may not appear to be useful!).

However, your use of it is just like any other buffer overrun: [your program has undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087066/4386278).

C++ does not check array bounds for you. That's your job.

Going past them can appear to work; it can cause a crash; it can instantaneously transport the sun to another part of the galaxy.

Just don't do it.

Comment: So *thats* how Richard Prior hacked the weather satellite to control the weather in that Superman movie!

Comment: so are moving from dragons flying out of our noses to transporting the sun to another galaxy. Why didn't I get this memo?

Comment: @bolov The sun was transported into a galaxy in which dragons flying out of noses is a common, every day occurrence

Comment: "Long long ago, in a galaxy beyond sight and sound..."

Comment: And I'm here, still stuck with nasal **demons**. You guys are way ahead of me!

Comment: @YSC Don't worry, the time travel might still kick in

Comment: At second glance `new int[0]` is very useful, which is why it's allowed. It eliminates having to check for special cases in your code. As long as you keep track of the number of elements along with the pointer, allocating 0 elements works just fine. `int *make_array(unsigned n) { return new int[n]; }`.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's right.